# Remotely Connect AWS with IntelliJ

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How do I REMOTELY connect AWS Elastic Beanstalk with IntelliJ?
I am new to AWS and Spring, and It will be quite difficult and unprofessional to upload WAR file again and again. Is there a way to update the project on server root, like we do for cPanels.

Comment: Yet, uploading the WAR again and again is more or less the standard way of doing it `:-)`.  You could write a script which uses AWS CLI commands to connect and deploy the WAR automatically.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please help me with the AWS CLI script

Comment: If you want to do it "profesionally" you setup CI/CD pipepine witch automatically gets new revisions of the app from the source code, builds it, tests and deploys to EB.